# Unquoting a variable name (to implement variable pointers)

Tags: quote, symbols

I know that if I have a variable with a function name, I can call it using `funcall`, like this

```
(setq func-ref 'my-func)
(funcall func-ref)
```

I am wondering if there's a similar functionality for variables (defined with `defvar`), so that I can set `var-ref` like this

```
(setq var-ref 'my-var)
```

and use it to get the value of `my-var` and/or update it.

EDIT: I want to use this functionality in a function which takes as argument a reference to a variable that will be changed in the function.

Comment: Just use  `(setq var-ref 'my-var)` and `(set my-var 42)`.

Comment: You could also look at `gv-ref` and `gv-deref`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `symbol-value` to look up dynamically bound variables.  The easiest way to ensure that is by using `defvar`/`defconst`/`defcustom` for such variables, that way they'll always be dynamically bound, even with lexical-binding enabled.  Plain `setq` will not do as soon as lexical binding is used and is discouraged for defining variables for that reason.

To change the value, use `set` instead of `setq` and give it a symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You can `eval` to recover the value of a variable symbol.  To modify it you can use `setf`:

```
(setq x 1)
(setq xref 'x)
(eval xref) ;; Returns 1
(setf (symbol-value xref) 2)
(eval xref) ;; Returns 2
```

The value of `x` is now 2

`setf` is the generalized version of `setq` that lets you place values in arbitrary "places" within an object. For example you can change elements within a list:

```
(setq x '(1))
(car x) ;; Returns 1
(setf (car x) 2)
(car x) ;; Returns 2
```

Comment: Does that mean I cannot have pointers (or references to variables)? I don't think your second example can be used in my case where I want to write a function that can change a variable (defined with `defvar`) whose name is given as an argument to the function.

Comment: Please do not suggest the use of `eval` unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Tohiko You can. I've edited the answer to make it do this.